# Proving function is strictly positive in a interval defined by coefficients

Tags: polynomials

> Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\dots+a_1x+1$. Prove that $f(x)$ is strictly positive if $$0<|x|<{1\over1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|}.$$

Any hints on how to start?

Comment: At $x=0$, the function is obviously positive because it is equal to 1. The problem is suggesting that there are no roots near 0. It is giving you a range of values for $x$ such that there are no roots of $f(x)$. Because $f(x)$ is a polynomial, it cannot become nonpositive without reaching zero. 

So, to start, assume $0 < |x| < \dfrac{1}{\displaystyle 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|}$. Then show that $f(x)>0$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe So we need to show Absolute value of root is greater than the reciporcal of sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(x)=f(x)-1=x\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix^{i-1}$ then  for $|x| < \dfrac{1}{1 + \sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|}$we have that $|x|<1$ and
$$|h(x)|\leq |x|\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|<1.$$
Therefore 
$$f(x)=1+h(x)\geq 1-|h(x)|>0.$$